# play framework application routes broken

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

am working on a play framework application: 
I have some routes

## user registration and login

```
GET       /register                 controllers.HomeController.registration()
```

while trying to reach

http://localhost:9000/register

it goes to

## user profile

```
+ nocsrf
GET     /:username              controllers.HomeController.account(username:String)
```

the project was working fine last week but ever since my computer had issues
I moved the project and formatted the computer. please guide.

i have tried to compile the project couple time but yet not working.
please .. help me solve this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes are resolved from top to bottom, so just put the more specific route before the more generic one.

# FIRST

GET       /register

#### MORE ROUTES IF YOU WANT

#FINALLY

GET     /:username

Comment: thank men: it worked: but can you explain for me about the order of routes in play framework
because I still have many routes that are not working too
let me have a bit explanation about generic and specific routes in play framework

I just won't figure it out  how to do so

Comment: :username is not restricted at all, any string matches with :username, even "register". So when Play tries to resolve which action should be invoked when receiving GET to /register, /:username is a good match for it. So you need to put /register before /:username